# Python not returning value from function

Tags: python, function

```
def main():
    sss = 0
    oa = 0
    calc (sss ,oa)
    print ("value = ",sss ,oa)

def calc (sss ,oa):
    sss = sss + 1
    oa = oa + 1
main()
```

why is print print ("value = ",sss ,oa) 0 0 and not 1 1

Comment: you're changing the value through calc, but the value your incrementing in calc (the sss) is a local variable, you are not doing anything to the value your trying to increment in main(). I suggest you [read this](http://www.python-course.eu/global_vs_local_variables.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand how local variables work in python. You are getting `0,0` because in `def calc (sss, oa)` your are modifying the local `sss` and `oa`, not the `sss` and `oa` variables that you are passing to `print` in your `main`.

There are many possible ways to achieve your task. However, try this modified version of your code that returns the local variables:

```
def main():
    sss = 0
    oa = 0
    sss, oa = calc (sss ,oa)
    print ("value = ",sss ,oa)

def calc (sss ,oa):
    sss = sss + 1
    oa = oa + 1
    return sss, oa
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Function arguments in python are passed by assignment. When assigning in python, a new object is created for immutable types while the new name acts as another reference to the same object for mutable types.

This means that passing integer variables to the calc function copies the objects and binds the copies to the local names since the built-in integers are immutable. This is in contrast to what would happen in the case of mutable types where the names would be references to the original objects.